# python parallel computing: split keyspace to give each node a range to work on

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, character-encoding

My question is rather complicated for me to explain, as i'm not really good at maths, but i'll try to be as clear as possible.

I'm trying to code a cluster in python, which will generate words given a charset (i.e. with lowercase: aaaa, aaab, aaac, ..., zzzz) and make various operations on them. 
I'm searching how to calculate, given the charset and the number of nodes, what range each node should work on (i.e.: node1: aaaa-azzz, node2: baaa-czzz, node3: daaa-ezzz, ...). Is it possible to make an algorithm that could compute this, and if it is, how could i implement this in python?

I really don't know how to do that, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table#Keyspace_partitioning

Comment: thanks for the hint, i'll try to figure how to apply these concepts concretely now ^^

Answer (score 1):

Any way that you could compute a small integer from the string would be fine for clustering.  For example, compute a hash with md5, and look at a byte of it:

```
import hashlib

s = "aaac"
num_nodes = 5 # or whatever
m = hashlib.md5(s)
node = ord(m.digest()[0]) % num_nodes

print node  # prints 2
```

This won't guarantee to evenly distribute all the strings, but it will be close.

Comment: i can't understand how to use your piece of code to know the "words range" to give to each node, could you be more precise please?

Comment: This code doesn't know anything about word ranges.  It takes a word (s in the sample), and determines a node number to assign it to.  The assignment isn't based on ranges, it's apparently random.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to treat your words as numerals in a strange base.  For example, let's say you have a..z as your charset (26 characters), 4 character strings, and you want to distribute among equally 10 machines.  Then there are a total of 26^4 strings, so each machine gets 26^4/10 strings.  The first machine will get strings 0 through 26^4/10, the next 26^4/10 through 26^4/5, etc.

To convert the numbers to strings, just write the number in base 26 using your charset as the numbers.  So 0 is 'aaaa' and 26^4/10 = 2*26^3 + 15*26^2 + 15*26 +15 is 'cppp'.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll see if i can do what i want using this method